# How do I download texture pack from Steam app?

Tags: steam, final-fantasy-15

I want to download the Final Fantasy 15 high resolution texture pack to my PC from the Steam App.

When I go to the store page to select the texture pack, it doesn't give me the option to download it, it just says "Play Game".

I have not downloaded the texture pack yet, so it should give me the option of downloading it from the app, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your library. Click on FFXV. Go to DLC. Choose the pack. Get back to library/FFXV and make a tick at the new dlc listed.